# Awk ignores printing a single column. sh -c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm having trouble trying to wrap this command inside the other command.

```
# Target Command:
/bin/df / | awk END' { gsub(/\%/, ""); print $5} '

# What I want:
/bin/sh -c " [command above goes here]"
```

I'm running into a problem with the awk and all the quotes... 
I've tried:

```
bin/sh -c "/bin/df / | awk END' { gsub(/\%/, "'"''"'"); print $5} '"
```

But the problem is that awk doesn't seem to print only column $5 in this instance.
How can I fix the above command `awk` command to print only column 5 (of the last line)?

PS: what I'm trying to do is to get the percentage of disk used (excluding the % sign). Since I'm calling it from a program that doesn't support pipes in an easy way, I'm using `sh -c`.

Comment: Why are you doing it through `sh -c`?

Comment: @thatotherguy if you want to execute the pipe from a program (which is not a shell) you need to hand it to a shell which can do pipes. this is typically done with sh -c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
/bin/sh -c "/bin/df | awk 'END{gsub(/%/, \"\", \$5); print \$5}'"
```

`$` also needs to be escaped.

As per @Ed's comment below if `$5` is not available in `END` block in some versions of awk then use:

```
/bin/sh -c "/bin/df | awk '{p=\$5} END{sub(/%/, \"\", p); print p}'"
```

Comment: `$0` and the fields `$5` etc. will only be populated in the END section with some awks, it's not POSIX. You need to save and use a variable if you want it to be portable.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for pointing it out. I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `"` and the `$`:

```
/bin/sh -c "/bin/df / | awk END' { gsub(/\%/, \"\"); print \$5} '"
```

The reason why you did not need to escape the `$` in your original line is: because it was guarded by `''`. But when you quote the ticks (with the double quotes) they lose that protective property.
The `"` need to be escaped because they would terminate your outermost double quotes too early.

But it is most likely easier to put everything into a shell script and start this. This also allows you some more lines like setting up the `PATH` and `IFS` and maybe doing platform specific searching of (g)awk and so on.

BTW: and I would add `-x nfs` (Linux) or `-t nonfs,nullfs` (BSD) if possible. Monitoring scripts are known to kill a system if started repeatingly (while the NFS server is unabaulable). Of course this asumes, you dont want to monitor NFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can let bash do the heavy lifting with exported functions:

```
myfunc() {
  /bin/df / | awk 'END { gsub(/\%/, ""); print $5} '
}
export -f myfunc

bash -c "myfunc"
```

This way, you don't have to mess around with unreadable escaping.